# How to retrieve and set the huge String data retrieved -- to a JTextArea in swing?

Tags: java, swing, list, recursion, jtextarea

I have 2 classes -A and B.I am building a GUI for retrieving a list of files. Class B is for recursion and returns a generic List of files. Class A is for GUI and retrieves the list of files and converts each file to a string.

Now, My problem is that when i call
System.out.println(SomeFileName.toString()); in Class B. the Output is BLAZING fast ! 
But when i retrieve the same list of files via Class A and append the output to a JTextArea --
then the processing becomes a Million times slower.

Can anybody give me a solution ? Should i use buffers ? or I was looking over, somewhere it was suggested that i use a Document for a JTextArea ! I am using NetBeans.

**Class A is coded like this :**

```
     List<File> hoohoo = cr.catalog(partition);
        Iterator<File> it = hoohoo.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            File myf = it.next();
            filesText.append(myf.toString() + NEWLINE);
        }
```

**Class B looks like this ::**

```
    public List<File> catalog(String file) {
    List<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>();
    File myfile = new File(file);
    File[] fileNme = myfile.listFiles();
    for (File name : fileNme) {
        if (name.isDirectory()) {
            fileList.add(name);
            List<File> fist = sub_Catalogue(name);
            Iterator<File> it = fist.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                fileList.add(it.next());
            }
        } else if (name.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(name);
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}

private List<File> sub_Catalogue(File name) {
    List<File> fileList2 = new LinkedList<File>();
    File[] names = name.listFiles();
    Humpty:
    if (names == null) {
        break Humpty;
    } else {
        HooHaa:
        for (File n : names) {
            if (n.isFile()) {
                fileList2.add(n);
            } else if (n.isDirectory()) {
                fileList2.add(n);
                List<File> fileList3 = sub_Catalogue(n);
                Iterator<File> uf = fileList3.iterator();
                while (uf.hasNext()) {
                    fileList2.add(uf.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList2;
}
```

Comment: i have many partitions in my system and data returned for all of them is done in a speedy way. Except for my C:\ drive which has Windows 7 installed on it and various other programs..

Comment: and should i add any listener to the JTextArea in Question?Would that change any thing? i can post code if needed here..

Comment: please post some code, we cant magically figure what's wrong

Comment: Just to echo the others, an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) would be really useful.

Comment: @Charles Goodwin : just posted the code, where i think is a huge problem. and to add : I have not any used Listeners for JTextArea: filesText.

Comment: Dont mind my use of unorthodox names.. ! i will change them during the final review.

Comment: @udit k: While not directly an answer to your question, but given you are listing files, you might take a different approach and create the file listing lazily.  See [File Browser GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui) for example code.  As to the class names, please consider the people who you expect to **read** the code, and post meaningful variable names for their sake.

Comment: @Andrew : recently i was reading on creating a JTree "lazily".. thanks.. This seems to be the same..

Comment: @Andrew: My bad. I am sorry.Wont post code without meaningful names here.

Comment: *"Wont post code without meaningful names here."* That is what I'd hoped.  Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely to be that the JTextArea is doing lots of work on each setText/append call. Calling that method a million times will grow the internal string a little bit at a time and do some work. You probably end up with an O(N^2)-like complexity on the size of the list.

Try the following: using a StringBuilder, combine all the strings in the list to form just a single string. Then call setText on the JTextArea using this single big string.

Comment: yep, i was reading on that too and on StringBuffer class.. thanks a ton. !

Comment: i want the retrieved Strings to appear on each consecutive line, the above solution for combining them wont solve this issue. :( but i will try using StringBuilder.

Comment: @udit: You can `append('\n')' as needed.

Comment: @udit: if it was not clear, trashgod meant StringBuilder.append, not JTextArea.append.

Answer (score -1):

A more efficient way to build the string that you will put as text to the JTextArea is to use a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
 List<File> hoohoo = cr.catalog(partition);
 Iterator<File> it = hoohoo.iterator();
 StringBuilder filesSB = new StringBuilder();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
     File myf = it.next();
     filesSB.append(myf.toString());
     filesSB.append("\n");
 }
 filesText.setText(filesSB.toString());
```

Here is an article on loading text efficiently in Swing:
http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/O.F.Rana/jdc/swing-nov7-01.txt

Comment: the thing here is that retrieving a huge list and then performing calculations on each String returned . Would it not Tax the TextPane even more ?? but lemme try it first.. will comment when i have tried it. thanks

Comment: I think the point is that you can add it piece by piece rather than all at once, no?

Comment: doc.insertString(); i used this .. used a Document too.. but no Text pane.. and no Effect on the result.. my C:\ drive which has a huge number of files, is still taking a huge amount of time.. to show up !

Comment: Ok, now i set a document in a JTextArea, the time to get the result just got reduced by Half ! Great ! Awesome ! thanks for the Idea.. But my Question still remains unanswered.... :( i will re-edit and post wat i have done with my class..

Comment: -1, A JTextArea is far more efficient than use a JTextPane. A JTextPane needs to support multiple fonts, colors, styles etc which adds to the overhead. Use a JTextArea for simple text.

Comment: @camickr: point taken, reducing the answer to just the StringBuilder